# retrieve image in react native after uploading in firebase database

Tags: firebase, react-native

i have uploaded an image to storage in  real time  firebase database and i want to render this image that i uploaded in my application how can i achieved that??? i tried the code below  but it did not work with me

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref('path/to/image.jpg');
const url = await ref.getDownloadUrl();

//render

<Image
  source={{ uri: url }}
/>
```

i expect to show the image that i uploaded in the emulator

[image: firebase storage]